# example of a uniform density function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, economics, descriptive-statistics

Could you, please, give an example (in biology, physics, economics etc.) of a constant density function, i.e. I would like to know the example of a density function $f_{X}(x)$ such that $f_{X}(x) = const$ for $x\in (a,b)$ for some $a < b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What a "flat region" means is not clear to me. Would the uniform distribution qualify?

Comment: I have clarified my question.

Comment: yes, I agree that the question is not good. There are plenty of applications.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the ultimate example of a 'flat' density functions is the
uniform family. For example a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1)$
often denoted $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ or $\mathsf{Beta}(1,1).$ You can
look at the uniform and beta families of distributions on Wikipedia.

Sometimes Bayesian statisticians want to use prior distributions that contain
very little information. Then one workable idea is to use a distribution that has a very large variance. Perhaps something like $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 0, \sigma=1000),$ which spreads most of its probability very 'thinly' over the interval
$(-3000, 3000);$ it's variance is $\sigma^2 = 1000^2.$ This distribution
does not have a constant value over any interval, but is "almost" flat
everywhere.

If you can say why you want a flat distribution, I (or someone else here)
might be able to give you an answer specifically attuned to your purpose.